# Is it a good idea to keep Sawtooth public key "public" like an Ethereum address?

Tags: cryptography, hyperledger, blockchain, ethereum, hyperledger-sawtooth

Suppose, given an agent belonging to a company, having its own pair of public / private keys, that you want to certify with confidence that it was really that agent belonging to that company to have written through a particular transaction the data on the blockchain. In *Ethereum*, you could publish your **address** on the company website while, in *Sawtooth*, how could I do? Is it possible to use **public key** or is this not good for security reasons? Is this a suitable use case for *Sawtooth*?

Comment: Take a look at the `identity` TP, may be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Frank! So the roles and rules allow to avoid the part of public key publication? But a third-party user who reads the data on the blockchain, how can he be sure about the identity of the writer of that data? Hypothesizing a supply-chain context, for example, a user reads the data and wants to be sure of the real identity of who wrote them, in short, that the company is not "boasting".

Comment: You have to look into zksnark or associated techs utilized by zcash to create transaction commitments, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public key is for public good and there is no reason not to widely publish it and make it available.

The usual problem with public-private keypairs is people leak the private key or do not secure the private key properly and have it lost or stolen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan! Could you give me an opinion on the use case presented in the above question? Because I don't understand how one can trust the identity of an *agent* who writes data inside the blockchain. That is, in Ethereum, for example, the agent publishes his address on his site and I am sure it is his, this is also necessary in Sawtooth or the management of **Roles** and **Policies** allows you to avoid performing this operation, since only specific agents (that have specific keys) can perform specific operations? Thank you!

Comment: In Sawtooth, transactions are signed by a private key. The transaction can be verified by anyone with the public key. So long as the private key is kept private, you can trust who signed the transaction.

In Sawtooth, transactions can be restricted to a certain set of public keys (1 or more keys). The restrictions can be for any transaction or just for a specific transaction family (such as the Settings Transaction Processor or the Intkey (Integer Key) Transaction Processor.